# C# ebay sdk ComboBox linking selectedindexchanged event to button click

Tags: c#, combobox

I am making a web request from button click event and selecting category from combo box index change event. How do I link my request made in the button click event to the category selection made from the combo box selected index changed event?

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            CustomFindingService service = new CustomFindingService();
            service.Url = "https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?";


            FindCompletedItemsRequest request = new      FindCompletedItemsRequest();
    request.categoryId = selectedItem.ToString();                
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (selectedItem.ToString() == "Cell Phones & Accessories")
    {
        this.comboBox2.Text = "";
        comboBox2.Items.Clear();
        this.comboBox2.Items.AddRange(catCellPhones2);

        selectedItem = "15032";               
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `selectedItem`? What is `catCellPhones2`? Why can't you just do `comboBox2.SelectedValue` in the `button3_Click_1` event?

Comment: I have 5 comboboxes and each populate a list of categories upon item selection in the previous combobox. I want to make one web request for the most current selected item in all of the comboboxes. I want to globalize the request from the button click event and select which category to request for from the combobox selectedindexchanged events.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wire up an instance of HttpWebRequest which is found in the System.Net namespace, take a look at this link which should give you everything you need to call

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

If you need anymore examples, give me a shout and ill see if i can did one out for you

Comment: I am making a ebay sdk web request.

Comment: i dont know there SDK, but it might be worth putting that into your question, so you dont get similar responses sending you in a possible wrong direction, but... youll probably still need to use the HttpWebRequest